# Implementing an MS Access database inside of android application instead of SQLite?

Tags: android, database, ms-access

Is there any way that I can use a Microsoft Access database inside my Android application instead of a SQLite database?

I have a pre-existing Access database with over 50 tables and re-writing this would be a pain. If anyone has any ideas on how I can implement accessing my Access database within my application, please let me know.

Comment: BTW, 74 questions and 6 upvotes cast won't encourage people to answer your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try to shove Microsoft Access into Android. Go with the past of least resistance and *migrate* your Access database to a supported DB.

SQLite has conversion tools to help [convert your existing Access database to SQLite.](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ConverterTools)

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way.  The LGPL [Jackcess library](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net).  I use it for my app, Panacea Database, which can handle Microsoft Access files on Android.

As the others have said, SQLite is the more Android-centered way of doing things, so you may want to consider going that route as well.

Comment: Im using Qt to make android application. Is it possible to use Jackcess library for Microsoft database access?