# Storing access db in the cloud

Tags: android, web-services, ms-access, cloud

I have one large access database which got 500-750 records. I used it daily for adding day to day transactions.I want to create an android application so that I can add records to the database on the way. In what way I can achive this? also any help in creating web service to access db from cloud will be useful...

Comment: May be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457729/implementing-an-ms-access-database-inside-of-android-application-instead-of-sqli